# Play animation only once on click

Tags: python-2.7, animation, matplotlib, tkinter

How can I make this animation function play once when I select any option from the drop down menu?

```
drop1 = ttk.OptionMenu(app, in1,'', 'Borough', 'Property Type')
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, animate, interval = 1000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using the below logic:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

var = StringVar()
array = [1, 2, 3]

def command(*args):
    print("Animation")

OptionMenu(root, var, 1, 2, 3).pack()

var.trace("w", command)

root.mainloop()
```

This makes use of `var.trace()` which allows you to trigger a command based on a variable either being read or written to. It also provides three arguments to the command which we're not using in the case so just enter `*args` when declaring the command to accept all given arguments.

You'll need to inject the code you use to run the animation into the command.